# Claims authentication SharePoint 2013 with Thinktecture identity provider

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, security-token-service, distributedcache

We have a strange issue around Claims authentication in SharePoint 2013.

Following is the scenario: 
Lets say we have a user called "John" in identity provider. We give "John" a new role called "Teacher" in identity provider. When John login for the first time to SharePoint via identity provider, we can see that john has a role "Teacher" in his claims. Every thing is Ok and works so for.

Now if we give another role (in addition to Teacher) to John lets say "Lecturer" in identity provider and john log in again through identity provider. We can not see that John has a new role "Lecturer" in his claims.

Does any one have a similar issue or know the reason why this is happening?

NB: In SharePoint log are som errors related to Distributed cache. e.g

Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache

Token Cache: Failed to add token from distributed cache for ""...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have John as a user in the site collection user information list. You need to clear John from that list before you can see his new role. See if John is present in the User Information list, and if so - delete him and see if that solves your issue...

```
http://siteCollection/_catalogs/users
```

Comment: I created new site collection and tested there. Doesn't work there either.

Comment: @Maddy Have you seen Wictor Wiléns post on the matter? http://www.wictorwilen.se/using-sharepoint-2013-with-thinktecture-identityserver-2

Comment: Yes i have seen this.

Comment: OK! I've never used Thinctecture before, so I'm really of no help here if it isn't a SharePoint problem. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It was typo error in the role name in identity provider. As Identity provider is developed and controlled by another company, we didn't have control over it. Found solution the hard way but at least issue is resolved.